# Smart light: change colour schedule

Tags: smart-home, lighting, philips-hue, smart-lights

With Philips Hue or Yeelight you are able to create a schedule to turn on the light.

I would like to set a timer to automatically change the light colour (i.e. before going to bed) only when the light is on and when the light is off then do nothing.

Is this possible with any product (preferably with Hue or Yeelight), anyhow?

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is, the platform is called **IFTTT**. Here is the link where it allows you to use the Hue:

[IFTTT & Hue](https://ifttt.com/hue)